# Select raw file based on number in Android

Tags: android, media-player

In the raw folder of this project there are 43 files with names ranging from note1 to note43. When given a certain number that note is played using mediaplayer, which requires using R.raw.filename. How can I use a variable in place of the name? Example:

```
int soundNum = 23;
String vaiableName = "note" + soundNum;
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.variableName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
public static int getResId(String variableName, Class<?> c) {
    Field field = null;
    int resId = 0;
    try {
        field = c.getField(variableName);
        try {
            resId = field.getInt(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resId;
}
```

in your case:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResId(vaiableName, R.raw.class));
```

I think i found this piece of code in a different post here on SO or a different website, so those credits goes to him/her. I use it in a lot of my android projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Resource.getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) API.